# how can I sort ElasticSearch result properly

Tags: elasticsearch

For example I have the following two documents with fields Id and Name(the name field is analyzed):

```
1,jack-in-box
2,box
```

When my query was "box", I got the both documents, but actually I only wanna the document 2, or getting document 2 above of document 1.
How can I query this please.

I know that the doc1 was tokenized to jack,in and box, so when I search box I would get the doc1. My current solution is creating another field called name_not_analyzed and it is not analyzed. But I have been wondering if we have the best way via query to solve this such I don't have to reindex. Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you want doc2 above document 1 or only doc2?

Comment: both ok, either only doc2 or doc2 was sorted above of doc1, thanks :)

Comment: doc2 should be above doc1 by default because of field length normalization (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/relevance-intro.html) can you show your query?

Comment: You should share your query that you are using in full.  Because it may be sorting, it could be relevancy score.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jgr pointed out in comment doc2 should be above doc1 by default unless you have your own ranking algorithm or if you are using `constant score query` or if you are only using `filter` which would give `score` of 1 to all documents

Now if you only want doc2, you could use [scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html)

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": "_source.name.toLowerCase()=='box'"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am accessing the `source` itself to check against, also using lowercase to match *BOX*, *Box* etc.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Cool, I got it! Awesome!

Comment: One more question please, how can I get it faster, it's very slow now ;-)

Comment: scripting will take few seconds but I guess scripting is the only way to get doc 2, but if you query like `{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": "box"
    }
  }
}` you will get doc 2 over doc 1 as doc 2 will be scored higher. The best solution is as you said is reindexing with `not_analyzed` so that you can use 'term filter` directly

Comment: Also, I think this should be **temporary solution** if you only want doc2 because script uses `_source` and it has to parse entire `_source` which is slow, It is much better to reindex as it will pay off in the long run.